# node Mqtt.js structuring code / best practices

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mqtt

So I've been searching for a long time on mqtt.js examples for structuring and best practices and haven't found anything worthwhile. thus [main] how do you structure your mqtt.js code in your node/express application?

[1] So the libraries mqttjs/async-MQTT provides some example on connecting and on-message but on a real app with lots of subscription and publishes how to structure code so that it initiliazes on the app.js and uses the same client (return from the mqtt.connect) for all the sub/pub in different files.

[2] and from the question[1] should my app only use 1 client for all the works or can use multiple clients as needed on multiple files (let's say I have 3 files mqttInit, subscriber, publisher. so if I use the init on subscriber and get a client should I export it or just make a new instance of a client on the publisher file)

[3] so the mqttjs API provides only an onMessage function so all subscribed topics message gets here thus I put a switch or a if else to manage this so if we have a lot of topics how do you manage this

[4] so my current setup is kind of messed up

this is the initializer file lets say'
mqttService.js

```
const mqtt = require("mqtt");
const { readFileSync } = require("fs");
module.exports = class mqttService {
  constructor() {
    this.client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://xxxxxxxxxxx", {
      cert: readFileSync(process.cwd() + "/certificates/client.crt"),
      key: readFileSync(process.cwd() + "/certificates/client.key"),
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    });
    this.client.on("error", (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
    this.client.once("connect", () => {
      console.log("connected to MQTT server");
    });
  }
};
```

subscriber.js
this is the function(subscribe()) that I call in app.js to init the mqtt thing

```
const { sendDeviceStatus, sendSensorStatus } = require("../socketApi");
const { client } = new (require("./mqttService"))();
function subscribe() {
  let state = {
    timer: false,
  };
  ...

  let topics = {
    ....
  },
  client.subscribe([...]);
  client.on("message", async (topic, buffer) => {
    if (topic) {
...
    }
  });
}
module.exports = {
  subscribe,
  client,
};
```

publish.js

```
const { AsyncClient } = require("async-mqtt");
const _client = require("./subscribe").client;
const client = new AsyncClient(_client);

async function sendSensorList(daqId) {
  let returnVal = await client.publish(
    `${daqId}-GSL-DFC`,
    JSON.stringify(publishObject),
    { qos: 1 }
  );
  console.log(returnVal);
  return publishObject;
}
.....
module.exports = {
  sendSensorList,
.......
};
```

so as you can see from the above code everything is kind of linked with one another and messed up thus I need some expo on how you structure code

thanks for reading, please feel free to provide any info and any info is much appreciated